# How can I only Get the Googlesheet from a list of files

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I found and modify this code and make it works the way I want :

```
function GS() {
  var COLsheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("COLLECTEUR");
  var fldr=DriveApp.getFolderById("186TzknoKVEfMZOz-WpB-H1XX5HnpzAyx");
  var files=fldr.getFiles();
  var link=[],f,str;
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    f=files.next();
    str='=hyperlink("' + f.getUrl() + '")';

    link.push([str]);
    
  }
  COLsheet.getRange(8,10, link.length, 1 ).setValues(link);//(range auquel on bake les valeurs)

  Logger.log(link)
}
```

but do you know if there is an easy way to get only the GSheet from the list ?

Comment: As another simple approach, I would like to propose replacing `var files=fldr.getFiles();` to `var files = fldr.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);`. By this, only Google Spreadsheet files are put into FileIterator. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getfilesbytypemimetype)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test for the type of file using [File.getMimeType()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getMimeType())

```
function GS() {
  var COLsheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("COLLECTEUR");
  var fldr=DriveApp.getFolderById("186TzknoKVEfMZOz-WpB-H1XX5HnpzAyx");
  var files=fldr.getFiles();
  var link=[],f,str;
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    f=files.next();
    if( f.getMimeType() === "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet" ) {
      str='=hyperlink("' + f.getUrl() + '")';
      link.push([str]);
    } 
  }
  COLsheet.getRange(8,10, link.length, 1 ).setValues(link);//(range auquel on bake les valeurs)

  Logger.log(link)
}
```